# How to show κ′(G) = δ(G) for δ(G) ≥ ⌊n/2⌋

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, graph-connectivity

I'm really struggling with the following proof.

> Prove that if G is an n-vertex graph and δ(G) ≥ ⌊n/2⌋, then κ′(G) = δ(G).

My first thought was to construct a proof by contradiction, however, it seems that this may not be a good approach since I would have to evaluate κ′(G) $\neq$ δ(G). My second thought was to use proving the contrapositive: If κ′(G) $\neq$ δ(G), then δ(G) < ⌊n/2⌋. But again this involves evaluating when κ′(G) = δ(G). Is there a better way to go about this proof or are either of these sufficient and I'm overlooking something. Thanks

Comment: A proof by contradiction could work. We have $\kappa'(G) < \delta(G)$ when there is an edge cut with multiple vertices on both sides; think about why this cannot work when $\delta(G)$ is too large. (A baby version of this is proving that when $\delta(G) \ge \lfloor n/2\rfloor $, $G$ must be connected.)

Comment: Why did you choose connectivity being less than δ(G) as opposed to greater than? I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the relationship between κ′(G) and δ(G)

Comment: You should already know that $\kappa'(G) \le \delta(G)$ for all graphs. (If not, then think about how we can delete $\delta(G)$ edges to disconnect a graph under any circumstances.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thank you for the response, that makes sense that $\kappa'$ can not be greater since deleting $\delta(G)$ edges will guarantee disconnecting the graph for any vertex with $\delta(G)$ edges. Also, thanks for the the question to consider when () gets too large. Right now my thoughts are suppose we are looking at a complete graph. In such a case, the edge connectivity is n-1 so edge connectivity must equal (). How can I connect this to all () > n/2?